# Python __init__ syntax

Tags: python, class, constructor

I'm confused about some examples I've seen of initializing classes using inheritance.  Some of them look like:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self, arg, parent = None):
        Bar.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Baz = arg
        etc.
```

While others are simpler:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        Bar.__init__(self)
        etc.
```

What is the purpose of using a "parent" argument to `__init__`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally passing `parent` is not something that's required, only when the parent class's constructor explicitly needs such an argument. This is used in some hierarchies, such as PyQt.

And a good idiom of parent class initialization is to use `super`:

```
class Child(Father):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Child, self).__init__()
```

Comment: But `super()` only works with new-style classes in Python 2, or Python 3. It doesn't work with old-style classes in Python 2. Make sure your base class is a new-style class (inherits from `object`).

Comment: @Keith: correct, although using old-style classes these days is not recommended, since it's a very old feature

Comment: Exactly, but some people still do it and the OP seemed to be following an old example. So I thought I'd point that out, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

In your example the variable "parent" is misleading. Simply the parent class COULD require additional arguments that must be provided

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        Pet.__init__(self,name)
        self.age = age
```

In this example the parent class Pet requires an attribute (name), and the child class provides it

As pointed out, use "super" syntax to call parent classes methods