# How to add attributes to a subclass of pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

I would like to add attributes to a subclass of DataFrame, but I get an error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>class Foo(pd.DataFrame):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar=None
...         
>>> Foo()


RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Although the below solves it, the interesting thing which leads from this question is **why** there is a maximum recursion depth exception, something to do with `DataFrame.__getattr__`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to write this as follows:

```
class Foo(pd.DataFrame):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Foo, self).__init__()
    self.bar = None
```

*See the [Python's `__init__` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013844/python-init-syntax) question.*

Comment: Just as a pointer: This solution will get you into trouble pickling Foo since you're setting self.bar = None you actually set a pandas attribute and pandas attributes doesn't get pickled. So basically you will loose all the added attributes from Foo.

Comment: There is a github issue about that: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2485. "Proper" subclassing of DataFrame isn't supported yet, see [this long standing issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/60), but progress is being made.

Comment: Just for reference, made an pickable subclass to DataFrame which has a custom attribute metadata: https://github.com/Jim-Holmstroem/MetadataDataFrame .
Another uglier possibility is to use DataFrame.name as attribute since that's the only 'metadata' that gets pickled in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [12]: class Foo(pd.DataFrame):
   ....:     def __init__(self, bar=None):
   ....:         super(Foo, self).__init__()
   ....:         self.bar = bar
```

which results in:-

```
In [30]: my_special_dataframe = Foo(bar=1)

In [31]: my_special_dataframe.bar
Out[31]: 1

In [32]: my_special_dataframe2 = Foo() 

In [33]: my_special_dataframe2.bar
```